# Create a Multidimensional Array via for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an onedimensional array which I want to store in a multidimensional array. Here an example:

```
[RE-10032, 130.4, 09.08.2020, 31.08.2020, Bezahlt, RE-10033, 150.22, 01.09.2020, 30.09.2020, Offen, RE-10034, 111.3, 01.10.2020, 16.10.2020, Offen]
```

And out of this Array, I want to create a multidimensional one:

```
[[RE-10032, 130.4, 09.08.2020, 31.08.2020], [Bezahlt, RE-10033, 150.22, 01.09.2020, 30.09.2020, Offen], [RE-10034, 111.3, 01.10.2020, 16.10.2020, Offen]]
```

The length of the array is not fixed, therefore you can divide the array every time by 5. So this is what I came up with:

```js
function ReceiveArray(values){
  var storevalues = values;
  var storevalueslength = storevalues.length +1;
  var multiarray = [];
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<storevalueslength; i++){
  if( i % 5 == 0 && i > 0){
       x++;
       y = 0;
       multiarray[[x][y]] = storevalues[i];
       y++;
    }
    else{
      multiarray[[x][y]] = storevalues[i];
      y++;
      
    }
  }
  Logger.log(multiarray);

  
}
```

My Idea was: Every time "i" is dividable by 5, x counts up and y is set to 0, so all of the following values get stored into the next array of the array. But for some reason, it is not working. I hope somebody has a solution :D

Comment: Have a look at the `modulo` operations in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Math

Answer (score 2):

Using [Array#slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) in a for loop makes it fairly easy.

The `for` loop increments by the desired length of the sub-arrays each iteration

```js
const arr = ['RE-10032', 130.4, '09.08.2020', '31.08.2020', 'Bezahlt', 'RE-10033', 150.22, '01.09.2020', '30.09.2020', 'Offen', 'RE-10034', 111.3, '01.10.2020', '16.10.2020', 'Offen']

const res = [],
  subLen = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += subLen) {
  res.push(arr.slice(i, i + subLen))
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code instantiates a new array `result` to contain the results and walks through the source array `arr`. The index to insert an item in the result array can be calculated by `Math.floor(i / n)`. We create a sub-array at each index if one does not already exist, and push the current item into the subarray.

```js
const arr = [
  'RE-10032', 130.4, '09.08.2020', '31.08.2020', 'Bezahlt', 
  'RE-10033', 150.22, '01.09.2020', '30.09.2020', 'Offen', 
  'RE-10034', 111.3, '01.10.2020', '16.10.2020', 'Offen' ]

function group(arr, n = 5) {
  const result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const j = Math.floor(i / n)
    result[j] = result[j] || []
    result[j].push(arr[i])
  }
  return result
}

console.log(group(arr))
```